# Convert from CategoryName to CategoryID when saving

Tags: c#, devexpress

[image]

based on the picture above I want to save the `CategoryID` of the `CategoryName` chosen in the combobox.

I did it once using `enum` but the `CategoryName` is from the database not from `enum`.

How can I do this? Or is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the LookUpEdit control if you'd like to have a combo box control that displays a string to the user but saves an ID value to the database.

Bind the LookUpEdit.Properties.DataSource property to an instance of IEnumerable, such as a DataTable or List. Then set the LookUpEdit.Properties.DisplayMember property to a string field/property in the datasource and the LookUpEdit.Properties.ValueMember property to an integer field/property in that data source that represents the value of the string.

See: [Standard Binding (to Simple Data Types)](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/116015/controls-and-libraries/editors-and-simple-controls/lookup-editors/standard-binding-to-simple-data-types)

-and-

[Advanced Binding (to Business Objects)](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/116016/controls-and-libraries/editors-and-simple-controls/lookup-editors/advanced-binding-to-business-objects)

For instance, if you have a Sql query such as:

```
SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories
```

And a method that executes this query and returns a DataTable "dtCategories" from this query, you might do:

```
myLookUpEdit.Properties.DisplayMember = CategoryName;
myLookUpEdit.Properties.ValueMember = CategoryID;
myLookUpEdit.Properties.DataSource = dtCategories;
```

The LookUpEdit.EditValue property will be the selected CategoryID.

Dale's solution seems to assume you are using an ASP.NET combo box control which is clearly not the case based on your screenshot. There is no "DataBind" method.